# What is the probability that the ﬁrst one picked is orange and the second is a ginger ale?

Tags: probability

It's my first year in university and I am literally struggling to understand my prof when he speaks-- he has a very VERY think accent. Long story short, I have to teach myself the content we are working on.

So here is a small question. There is a bunch a pop in a bag, 3 are cola, 3 are orange, 1 is a gingerale and 9 are lemon-limed.

What is the probability that the ﬁrst one picked is orange and the second is a ginger ale?

I had thought it would be simple, (1/16) x (3/16) = answer, and I ended up with 1.17%. However the answer is wrong and it should be 1.25%.

If you could help that would be much appreciated!

I was unable to afford the textbook and cannot use that as a reference...However I can use this answer as a "base" or "building" block to answer all my other practice questions!

Comment: One thing you need to be careful about is: do you put the orange back after you pick it out?

Comment: I would really recommend that you get yourself the textbook for the class; see if it, or an earlier edition of it, is available in the library. Perhaps form a study group, or find a classmate with the text, to plan "study sessions." It would really help you, given your situation, to have a reference text for better understanding the material.

Comment: Those think accents are a problem.

Comment: @WillJagy 8) Problem, maybe. But having a think accent is perhaps better than having a "non-think" accent!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oops: you forgot to re-calculate the number of pops in the bag after removing one pop: after picking the first soda-pop, you have only $15$ left for the second pick.

Try computing $\dfrac 3{16} \cdot \dfrac{1}{15}$

Comment: ...wow...I feel dumb. But thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. No reason to feel "dumb" - we all overlook "simple" things sometimes!

Comment: @Amzoti Hahahahaha...Now I'll have to just wait for whenever the next tally occurs! Thanks!

Comment: @amWhy: You are very welcome, but it is also very well deserved!